# How to pass a password with punctuation characters to 'mount' command?

Tags: samba, scripting, password, mount, bash

I have a shell script that mounts several samba shares one after the other. I want my users to have to enter in their password only once. I can pass in a password using the following,

mount -v -t smbfs -o nodev,nosuid //$user:$pass@my.host.com:/share /Volumes/share

This doesn't work when there are weird characters such as '^' or '.' in the password.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not using @$host

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the **user** and **password** options for the `mount.cifs` command (see man page `mount.cifs(8)`) like `mount -o ...,user="foo",password="bar" //example.com:/share` or you use the **credentials** option to provide the path to a file containing the user credentials (also see `mount.cifs(8)`).

Answer (score 2):

You have to URL encode the special characters (weird characters) on a Mac, because "mount_smbfs: -o user: option not supported". So, in your example, '^' = %5E

URL Encoding here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enclosing the password phrases in quotes?

Comment: rather single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround the entire options expression with quotes, i.e. mount -v -o "...".